# Can a splash screen activity have rounded corners on transition?

Tags: android, animation

I want my splash screen activity to have rounded corners on transition. So that when it slides down, and I go to the next activity the corners of the activity that is going down (splash screen) are rounded and not square.

I've tried setting the background of the whole activity transparent and gave it an image background with rounded corners, however, in the corners, my phone's home screen shows and not the next activity (makes sense I suppose, but now what I want) and I've tried giving it a background with down-margins, but it cuts the background as soon as the transition starts. No sure what else I can try. Is this even possible to do?